# Why are there on certain pages no headings?

Tags: sectioning, header-footer, chapters, sections-paragraphs, scrlayer-scrpage

I am wondering why the chapter is not written down on the heading (as I marked red). I guess it has something to do with \section*{}. Does anyone know how to fix this?

[image]
[image]

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} % F�r farbige Tabellenzellen
\usepackage{colortbl} 
\titleformat*{\section}{\normalfont\huge\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsection}{\normalfont\Large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\subsubsection}{\large\bfseries}
\titleformat*{\paragraph}{\normalsize\bfseries}
\newcounter{tblerows}
\expandafter\let\csname c@tblerows\endcsname\rownum
\usepackage{tablefootnote}
\usepackage[sort&compress]{natbib}
\usepackage{footnote}
\setcitestyle{square}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{upgreek}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{supertabular}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{mathptmx}         
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsbsy}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amstext}
\usepackage{lipsum}                 % Erzeugen von Blindtext
\usepackage{booktabs}               % huebsche Tabellen % Subfigures
\usepackage{xcolor}                 % Farben
\usepackage{booktabs}               % hübsche Tabellen
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\usepackage[nottoc]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{selinput}
\usepackage[capitalize]{cleveref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand*{\quelle}[1]{\par\raggedleft\footnotesize Quelle:~#1}
\newcommand*{\EigeneAbbildung}[1]{\par\raggedleft\footnotesize Eigene Abbildung~#1}
\usepackage[headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\rightmark}
\ofoot{\pagemark}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\bfseries}
\KOMAoptions{onpsinit=\setstretch{1}}
\renewcommand*\chaptermarkformat{}
\renewcommand*\chapterpagestyle{scrheadings}


\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{color} %red, green, blue, yellow, cyan, magenta, black, white
\definecolor{mygreen}{RGB}{28,172,0} % color values Red, Green, Blue
\definecolor{mylilas}{RGB}{170,55,241}

\begin{document}
\section*{Abstract}
fngf
\newpage
dgdfbhdthnfghnrfgfgtfrdfvjdnlsedvglneas
\end{document}
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

`article` ordinarily uses the contents of `\title{...}` and `\author{...}` to serve as the running heads, and applies these when `\maketitle` is issued.  Since I don't see any of these in your example, the running heads are blank.

You can set the running heads you want by issuing the command

```
\markboth{<left heading text>}{<right heading text>|
```

somewhere after `\begin{document}`.  If you want to change the values,
simply issue another `\markboth` command with the new values.
If you are changing only the right-hand heading, you can use
`\markright` instead, with a single argument.

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```latex
\usepackage[headsepline,automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
```

With the twosided `article` classs option `automark` does the same as

```latex
\automark[subsection]{section}
```

So each `\section` command (without star) sets a left mark and clears the right mark and each `\subsection` (without star) sets a right mark.

So, with

```latex
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\rightmark}
\ofoot*{\pagemark}% <- changed to get the page number on plain pages too
```

only (non-starred) subsections will get header entries.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,
  headheight=13.6pt% <- added to avoid the warnings regarding the head height
]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[headsepline,
  automark,% does the same as \automark[subsection]{section} for twosided article class
  singlespacing=true% <- added
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\rightmark}% do you want only subsections in page headers?
\ofoot*{\pagemark}% <- changed to get the page number on plain pages too
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\bfseries}
%\KOMAoptions{onpsinit=\setstretch{1}}% replaced by option singlespacing=true

\begin{document}
\section*{Abstract}
\lipsum[1-20]
\section{Numbered section}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{Numbered subsection}
\lipsum[41-60]
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately, I do not know/understand how the desired result should look like.

If there should be the sections in header on even pages and subsections in header on odd pages, you have to use

```latex
\ihead{\headmark}
```

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,
  headheight=13.6pt% <- added to avoid the warnings regarding the head height
]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[headsepline,
  automark,% does the same as \automark[subsection]{section} for twosided article class
  singlespacing=true% <- added
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}% <- changed: sections on even pages, subsections on odd pages
\ofoot*{\pagemark}% <- changed
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\bfseries}
%\KOMAoptions{onpsinit=\setstretch{1}}% replaced by option singlespacing=true

\begin{document}
\section*{Abstract}
\lipsum[1-20]
\section{Numbered section}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{Numbered subsection}
\lipsum[41-60]
\end{document}
```

If the sections should be in page header on both even and odd pages, you can use

```latex
\ihead{\leftmark}% <- changed: only sections in page header
```

Or you could replace option `automark` by macro `\automark[section]{section}`.

Example:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,
  headheight=13.6pt% <- added to avoid the warnings regarding the head height
]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[headsepline,
  %automark,% does the same as \automark[subsection]{section} for twosided article class
  singlespacing=true% <- added
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[section]{section}% <- added
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}% <- changed
\ofoot*{\pagemark}% <- changed
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\bfseries}
%\KOMAoptions{onpsinit=\setstretch{1}}% replaced by option singlespacing=true

\begin{document}
\section*{Abstract}
\lipsum[1-20]
\section{Numbered section}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{Numbered subsection}
\lipsum[41-60]
\end{document}
```

Starred sections, subsections etc. do not set marks automatically. But you can use `\markboth` and `\markright` to do this manually.

For the starred section you could use

```latex
\section*{Abstract\markboth{\MakeMarkcase{Abstract}}{\MakeMarkcase{Abstract}}}
```

which sets the left and the right mark or

````latex
\section*{Abstract\markboth{\MakeMarkcase{Abstract}}{}}
``` which sets the left mark and clears the right mark

Example:

``` latex
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}% only for dummy text
\usepackage{setspace}

\usepackage[paper=a4paper,left=25mm,right=25mm,top=25mm,bottom=25mm,
  headheight=13.6pt% <- added to avoid the warnings regarding the head height
]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[headsepline,
  %automark,% does the same as \automark[subsection]{section} for twosided article class
  singlespacing=true% <- added
]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\automark[section]{section}% <- added
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\headmark}% <- changed
\ofoot*{\pagemark}% <- changed
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape\bfseries}
\addtokomafont{pagenumber}{\bfseries}
%\KOMAoptions{onpsinit=\setstretch{1}}% replaced by option singlespacing=true

\begin{document}
\section*{Abstract\markboth{\MakeMarkcase{Abstract}}{\MakeMarkcase{Abstract}}}
\lipsum[1-20]
\section{Numbered section}
\lipsum[21-40]
\subsection{Numbered subsection}
\lipsum[41-60]
\end{document}
````